# How to initialize object by interface?

Tags: typescript

I have custom class and implemented interface:

```
interface IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort {
   type: string;
   id: number;
   name: string;
}

export class FilterWeekScheduleClass extends Filter {
  public constructor(public model: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort) {
    super(model);
  }

  public getModel() {
        return this.model.type;
  }

}
```

When I create instance of this class I pass `model` in constructor with type `IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort`.

How to initialize object `model` by default If passed model as empty object: `{}`?

Because when I call method: `getModel()` it returns an error: no property `type`.

Comment: *"How to initialize object `model` by default If passed model as empty object: `{}`?"* Can you *show* us what you mean by that? I'm wondering if I'm reading it correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check if its null and set it

```
interface IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort {
   type: string;
   id: number;
   name: string;
}

export class FilterWeekScheduleClass extends Filter {
  public constructor(public model: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort) {
    if(model == null) model = new FilterWeekScheduleClassShort();
    super(model);
  }

  public getModel() {
        return this.model.type;
  }

}
```

Comment: `null` isn't an "empty object `{}`".

Comment: true but its a little confusing to what he wants. Your answer is correct too. My other question is why does getModel return a type inside model instead of the model..

Answer (score -1):

> How to initialize object `model` by default If passed model as empty object: `{}`?

It's not allowed to be an empty object; your interface clearly says it has three required properties.

If some/all of those properties are optional, you could mark them optional with a `?` between the property name and `:` in the interface, but if they aren't optional, then passing `{}` into the constructor is an error, and TypeScript is correct to raise it.